# Partial load using manual sql query with EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5.0 and Code first and need to populate an array of entities using manual sql query.
However, I don't need to load the whole entity from db, but only few fields.
I don't need tracking also.

Both

```
Context.Set<TEntity>().SqlQuery(queryText, parameters)
```

and

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(queryText, parameters)
```

are throwing an exception:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'XXX_Type'. A member of the type, 'XXX_Some_Not_Loaded_Property', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Are there any ways to force EF to ignore missing fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default values to do "select as" for example

```
Select Col1, 0 as Col2, getdate() as DateCreated from Table1
```

In the above the Table1 can have an integer column named Col2 but we are not selecting it. Instead we select 0 as *Col2* and this will not cause any problems.

Similarly I am selecting current date as DateCreated though there could have been a column in the database called DateCreated.

This should trick EF. You should probably still search how to disable tracking lest it overwrite the DB row with these default values.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick, but still looking for more elegant solution